# STSADM: Scripting activaton/deactivation of web app level features

Tags: stsadm

I am writing a script to activate/deactivate certain features and there are a couple web application scoped features and when i test the commands, the feature status doesnt change.

Im using:

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -if {guid} -url {url}
```

Im not sure how else to do it.

If im not clear, shufler (in the comments below has it worded differently).

Comment: My assumption about what you're asking is that the web application feature is inactive and after running the activatefeature operation it is still inactive. Is this correct?

Comment: -if should be -id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deactivating and then activating again using the following commands:

```
  stsadm -o deactivatefeature -id C2EC140A-FF1B-4828-8238-1E37704E53A4 -url http://testwebappl -force

  stsadm -o activatefeature -id C2EC140A-FF1B-4828-8238-1E37704E53A4 -url http://testwebappl -force
```

Note: Replace the name of Feature GUIDs and web application URL with actual ones.

Important: it is recommended to run above commands as a .bat file to avoid SharePoint GUI timeouts during features activation/deactivation

Comment: If I used the url that appears in central admin they worked. For instance, I have a webapp that is http://site-sbx1.domain.sbx, but in central admin in appears as http://site-sbx1. Strange how it didnt work with the full URL.